# Zoom of LOB columns is not enabled; check Result preferences

Tags: hana

In HANA Studio I hava a LOB Column which contains text.

I see part of the text in the result view.

When I double click on the cell (which usually shows the whole content) I get the message:

Zoom of LOB columns is not enabled; check Result preferences

Unfortunately I do not find this preference. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function can be enabled in

```
    SAP HANA Studio Preferences 
    -> SAP HANA 
     -> Runtime 
      -> Result : [X] Enable zoom of LOB columns.
```

This information can also be found by searching the built-in documentation (hotkey F1) with the keywords "zoom lob".

Generally, the built-in documentation is a really good place to start looking for information like that. It also covers the command reference for SQL, SQL Script and the XS development.

Comment: Also THX for the hint with the documentation